# Where is the button "create registry" in the google cloud platform console for google iot?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, cloud, iot

In the documenation for the Google IoT Cloud https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/devices it claims i should go to the console: https://console.cloud.google.com/iot/registries and click create registry, but there is no button to do this. I can only do this in the console using the gcloud iot command.

I've have tried clicking through the console, but find it very hard to navigate. Where can I see my registered devices?

Comment: On my environment, I do indeed see a button called CREATE REGISTRY at the location:  https://console.cloud.google.com/iot/registries

Could it be that you are logged into the Google Cloud Platform as a user that doesn't have sufficient permissions to create registries?  That may hide the button?

Comment: I have created registries/devices using the console tool. So I believe it is not a permissions error. Strangely the link redirects me to https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/cloudiot.googleapis.com?returnUrl=%2Fiot%2Fregistries where i can select a project, but nowhere do i see a button CREATE REGISTRY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button "create registry" exists, but I had to first select a project, and then select "Google IoT" in the Navigation menu on the left hand side. If i do not do it in that order, I will not be navigating to the right menu screen. A direct link that includes the project has the following form:

https://console.cloud.google.com/iot/registries?folder=&organizationId=&project={project-id}